# quickblox web how to upload profile picture

Tags: quickblox

I'm trying to upload a profile picture (blob_id) from a javascript document and I can't find a way, I don´t know if I should use this snippets or even how to use it :(

I'll be so thankfull if you could help me

Thanks

```
QB.users.update({ id: user_creds.user_id, website: "http://quickblox.com"},   function(error, response){
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        // Success
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry about this. We'll be beefing up the documentation soon.

Here's how to upload a profile picture

We'll have a file input:

```
<input type="file" id="picture" />
```

Then assuming you have jQuery in your environment, we'll reference it like this:

```
var profile_picture = $("#picture")[0].files;
```

Then you upload the file to Quickblox AWS like so:

```
QB.content.createAndUpload({file: profile_picture, public: true}, function(error, response) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("upload didn't work");
    } else {
        var blob_id = response.id;
    }
});
```

As you can see, the ID of the blob is the `id` field of the response.

You then add this blob ID as the `blob_id` field of a new user when you create him/her:

```
QB.users.create({login: "username_here", password: "password_here", blob_id: blob_id_here}, function(error, response){
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {

    }
});
```

I made a page which demos the uploading functionality of the Javascript SDK - you can check it out here: http://www.quickblox.com/alex/websdk/upload.html

Comment: thank you very much for your quick answer, i'll let you know as soon as i try it if i'm able to make it work! :)

Comment: No problem. If you have any more questions, I'd be happy to help. :-)

Comment: hi, i have a quick question, is it possible connect a 1 and 1 web chat with the chat in my iOS App??