# Quickblox Message Attachments

Tags: quickblox

In reference to this question: [quickblox web how to upload profile picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676110/quickblox-web-how-to-upload-profile-picture/23682743#23682743)

I would like to attach the uploaded file to a new message.

```
 QB.content.createAndUpload({file: profile_picture, public: true}, function(error, response) {
     if (error) {
         console.log("upload didn't work");
     } else {
         var blob_id = response.id;
         // Example HERE //
         var attachment = {
           id: response.id.toString(),
           name: response.name,
           type: "photo",
           url: response.path,
           name: response.name,
           'content-type': response.content_type
          };
         QB.chat.message.create({
           attachments: [attachment]
         },...)
     }
 });
```

The message is created (see photo below) but the name and content-type values are not saved into quickblox.  The photo below shows a file attached using Q-municate app, the second content is from the code referenced above.  Can you let me know the correct was to add an attachment to a chat message.   Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYYR4.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way is to log **response** and check **response.name** and **response.content_type** - they can be null by some reason

In that case you can manually set them or so:

```
var attachment = {
           id: response.id.toString(),
           name: response.name,
           type: "photo",
           url: response.path,
           name: "my image",
           'content-type': "image/jpeg",
          };
```